# Git overriding .project file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

This is is a simple question. When I switch between branches my eclipse files get deleted in my project because they are not in my repository. .gitignore only works when checking in, not when switching branches. How can I keep my .project files in my project filed while using git?

Thanks

Comment: If the `.project` file is in the `.gitignore` then it shouldn’t be removed when switching branches.

Comment: what is the command to switch branch i use "git checkout <branch name>"

Comment: That’s the correct command to use. See rob’s answer below, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a .project file was committed to the repository before it was added to .gitignore, it won't be ignored. You need to remove it from the repository. Since you probably want to keep it in your working tree, try this:

```
git rm --cached .project
```

Comment: awesome thanks i had removed it in another branch but not on my master